# java file constructor when file not present on local disk

Tags: java, constructor

i want to instantiate File in java, but the file does not reside on my local disk, it resides on a http server. I tried to do something like

```
File file = new File ("http://myserver.com/abc.txt");
```

but get an exception. How to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

```
String data = "";
try {
    // Create a URL for the desired page
    URL url = new URL("http://myserver.com/abc.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        data += str + "\n"
    }
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
System.out.println(data);
```

You can't create a file, you have to use readers.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to use the `URL` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/index.html